# Channel.id () has been removed in netty4.0 final version, how can I solve?

Tags: java, netty, channel

We update to netty4.0 final version, but Channel.id () has been removed.

We need to take the initiative to send a message server to the client, how to find the appropriate Channel? We do not deal directly with the completion handler returned to the client, but the process needs to be transferred to another server and then return to send to the client.

Before we use Channel.id () can be done, but Channel.id () has been removed, what alternative solutions do?With channel.hashcode () can?

Comment: Yeah.... that was an 11th hour nasty surprise ! Following this question with interest....

Comment: It's coming back in 4.1: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been some issues raised on Github about this removal. Norman indicates that you could use Channel.hashcode() but it is not guaranteed to be unique:

https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/1540

Another idea would be to create a custom ChannelGroup, but that brings its own complications, discussed briefly here:

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1589

Comment: Trustin is bringing back a variant of channel id in 4.1.0: https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1810

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple counter:

```
public class SimpleChannel extends NioSocketChannel {
    protected static final AtomicLong nextId = new AtomicLong(0);

    protected long id = nextId.getAndIncrement();

    public SimpleChannel() {
    }

    public SimpleChannel(SocketChannel socket) {
        super(socket);
    }

    public SimpleChannel(Channel parent, Integer id, SocketChannel socket) {
        super(parent, id, socket);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Setting custom class to Bootstrap:

```
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
Bootstrap clientFactory = new Bootstrap();
clientFactory.group(workerGroup);
clientFactory.channel(SimpleChannel.class);
```

For server a bit more difficult:

```
public class SimpleServerChannel extends NioServerSocketChannel {
    private static final InternalLogger log = InternalLoggerFactory.getInstance(HttpServerChannel.class);

    @Override
    protected int doReadMessages(List<Object> buf) throws Exception {
        SocketChannel ch = javaChannel().accept();

        try {
            if (ch != null) {
                buf.add(new SimpleChannel(this, ch));
                return 1;
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            log.warn("Failed to create a new channel from an accepted socket.", t);

            try {
                ch.close();
            } catch (Throwable t2) {
                log.warn("Failed to close a socket.", t2);
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Setting custom class to ServerBootstrap:

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
b.channel(SimpleServerChannel.class);
```